# Browser cache control and adaptive images

Tags: php, http-headers, browser-cache

I am developing a website whose main content is images, that i have put in the background as `<img>` tags (having them as a CSS background property managed by media-queries is not an option).

I have exported 6 size versions of each image, set a cookie from Javascript indicating the user screen size properties, in a way that i can, from PHP, provide an image that is relevant to the client : ***width=1680px*** for large screens, ***width=800px*** for medium sized screens etc. AND i have a special layout for small screens ***<=560px*** that completely hides the slideshow and only print useful text content, in which case PHP outputs a 1x1px transparent image to save bandwidth.

By definition of that architecture, the URL to an adaptive image is constant and i can't control browser cache by adding a parameter to the URL.
But my problem is, is some cases, mainly that of a change in orientation (let's say a mobile that has a width of 800 CSS pixels and a height of 480 CSS pixels) a "wrong" image version is retrieved from the browser cache and not from the server.

I DO want to cache the images, but for the exact same URL, let's say http://www.mysite.com/media/image/s1/id38/images/image1-318970.jpg, i want to be able to control - from PHP and the headers that are sent - different cached versions of the file (relative to each actual file version on disk). 
I have looked into the `ETag` header, but i'm not sure where to go from there nor how to generate `ETag` values.

Has someone already solved that or similar?

Comment: If you have control over the image src, why can't you append a query string param?

Comment: Why not use jQuery, you can then only have say 2 images 1 low and 1 hi res, scaling the image to fit any size of screen, and use the on `$(window).resize()` to also handle orientation

Comment: @crush Because i retrieve screen props from $_COOKIE values, that are not known at HTML generation time, but only when an image file is requested. My [...].jpg URLs actually point to a PHP script that uses the $_COOKIE values to send back the appropriate image size version.

Comment: You can still append a `?1284128941` "where the number is the current timestamp" to the url before the PHP is executed. `<img src="myimagegenerator.php?182481284128" />` for example would keep whatever you served from being checked in the cache first.

Comment: @Lawrence Cherone : because some browser will start downloading the hi-res image even before jQuery tells them that they only need the low-res one. Those browsers will downloads 2 images instead of one.

Comment: @crush : just tried your 2nd proposition and in that case no image ever gets cached. I do want them to be cached, but one cache for each size version.

Comment: Instead of appending the date, you could append the size of the img, and the actual base img's src as query params: `myimagegenerator.php?src=base_src.jpg&w=800` browser caches are a simple hashtable, with the key being the URL.

Comment: @crush : again, the requested size is not known at HTML generation time but only when the image is requested.

Comment: Write it with Javascript on page generation, as Javascript can detect it before the IMG request is sent.

Comment: @crush : some browsers WILL start downloading the image before src is modified so that's not acceptable.

Comment: @darma That's not true if you write the src of the imgs with Javascript

Comment: @crush : if i completely write (and not just replace) the src of the images, you're right that it won't start downloading anything before JS is executed. but i still want the images to be accessible (robots, JS disabled...) so it's not an option sorry. my question relates to browser cache control and http headers.

Comment: the url may be constant in the page source, but that doesn't mean you can't dynamically change it after the fact via JS. simply rewrite the url with cache-buster parameters + new resolution as a response to a screen rotation event.

Comment: @darma `"I have exported 6 size versions of each image, set a cookie from Javascript indicating the user screen"` Your page relies upon Javascript being active anyways.

Comment: @crush : yes it relies upon JS to retrieve the appropriate image size version, but there still is a default image size provided for the non-JS browsers / robots.